# Using MMDrawer only in sub navigation view

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

I'm new to swift and iOS programming. Recently, I was exploring Drawer options and tried MMDrawer tutorial as explained in this [link](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/left-side-menu-navigation-drawer-example-with-swift/). I followed it step by step and it works great in a single view. ie, app loads to central view and I can swipe right / left to access drawer controllers.

Now, I want to add a tab bar controller before my current view, ie, hierarchy is

```
tab view controller [tab 1]---> Nav Controller --> drawer central view (swipe action takes place in here)
                    [tab 2]---> Nav Controller --> Different controller view
```

But due to code in appDelegate (central view, left nav and right nav instantiation), I directly land to my central view and tab bar doesn't appear in that case. I believe that instead of instantiating all of the code in appDelegate, I have to instantiate it in one of the sub view class. But I couldn't find any resources online.